# What is the opposite of a prefix?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, antonyms

In following, the word *string* refers to a sequence of letters.

If **A** is a *prefix substring* of **B**. Then **B** is a ________ of **A**.

**Examples:**

1. *ban* is a prefix substring of *banana* so *banana* is a ________ of *ban*?
2. In lexicographical ordering, prefix substrings sort before their ________s.

The words *extension* and *continuation* appear to only denote the part that comes *after* the prefix substring (e.g. *ana*).

Any single word or multiple words will do.

Comment: *Completion*, perhaps?

Comment: The opposite of prefix is suffix, but you are probably looking for ***affixes***: Grammar. a bound inflectional or derivational element, as a prefix, infix, or suffix, added to a base or stem to form a fresh stem or a word, as -ed added to want to form wanted, or im- added to possible to form impossible.

Comment: Agreed, affix. See also: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/701

Comment: I don't think *affix* is what you want; that refers to all things like prefixes and suffixes, but not also the stem or root to which they are attached. If I understand you correctly, you want to know what you call *unhappy* in relation to *un-*, not just *-happy*. In that case I think you're stuck with *word*. (Also, note that in English *ban-* is not a prefix of *banana*; *banana* is a single morpheme.)

Comment: @1006a I'm not talking here about grammatical prefixes, rather just speaking about strings as items.

Comment: If you're not talking about grammatical or linguistic units, then I'm really not sure what you're asking. In my world, the items known as strings are heavier than threads but lighter than ropes, completely free of prefixes, and generally unrelated to bananas, so I think you're probably talking about some specialized terminology (programming?) which you should specify.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have references for this, but I would be inclined to refer to your unnamed elements as *superstrings*, because your question is not really about prefixes, but about (prefixed) *substrings*; and a string that contains substrings can easily and logically be referred to as a superstring.  (If you want to be more specific about it, you could call them "containing superstrings", which seems more appropriate in your example 2.)

Comment: It would have to be *prefix superstring* as *nan* is a substring of *banana*, but not a *prefix substring*. So too is *banana* a superstring of *nan* but not a prefix superstring of *nan*.

Comment: It seems to me that "prefixishness", if you will, can only be quality of the substring, so calling something a "prefix superstring" is somewhat contradictory.  If it's already explicit in your text that you're dealing with prefix substrings only (not all substrings), then referring to the "superstring" seems clear enough.

Comment: Maybe the terms would need reversing, as *prefix superstring of "nan"* could be understood as *prefixing* "nan", i.e. extending it to the left, while a *suffix superstring* would extend beyond its end. *Suffix**ing** superstring* may be the clearest term.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably do well to use the word **elongation**.

> *ban* is a prefix substring of *banana* so *banana* is an **elongation** of *ban*.

The word **extension** came to mind first, but in computer science, *extension* refers frequently to a filetype extension following a dot, so that could be confusing when used in a separate context.  **Elongation** carries the same meaning without the risk of confusing readers or listeners.

Per [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elongation) definition **2**:

> a : the state of being elongated or lengthened; also : the process of elongating
>
> b : something that is elongated

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. Any way to clarify that I indeed mean *banana* and not *ana*?

Comment: @Adam I reread your question and I think I misunderstood the first time I read it.  Your question is clear after all, I will edit my answer to reflect that.